# tinytex warnings due to T1 fontenc and latin1 log file

Tags: r, utf-8, latex, iso-8859-1, tinytex

**Problem**

I run `tinytex::latexmk()` on a file with (a) UTF-8 encoding, (b) T1 font encoding, (c) overfull hbox containing an accented character. This creates a log file in *latin1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding*, causing warnings from `tinytex`.

**Reproducible example**

```
tinytex::latexmk("tiny.tex")
## [1] "tiny.pdf"
## Warning messages:
## 1: In xfun::read_utf8(log) :
##   The file tiny.log is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 51
## 2: In grep("^(LaTeX|Package [[:alnum:]]+) Warning:", x) :
##   unable to translate 'r/bx/n/10 vari-able di-cot<f3>mica\T1/cmr/m/n/10 . ' to a wide string
## 3: In grep("^(LaTeX|Package [[:alnum:]]+) Warning:", x) :
##   input string 51 is invalid
```

where `tiny.tex` contains

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item In this line we get an overfull hbox because the word \textbf{variable dicotómica}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**System information**

R 4.3.1 using `tinytex` 0.46 and `xfun` 0.40 with TeXLive 2023.20230613-3 on a Debian/GNU Linux (testing) system, running an en_US.UTF-8 locale. The TinyTeX distribution is not installed, i.e., the R package `tinytex` calls the system TeXLive. We have seen the [same kind of problem](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34438&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337) on Windows systems as well, though.

**Workaround**

I can avoid the issue by not using the T1 font encoding, i.e., by omitting or commenting the second line in `tiny.tex`. Then OT1 font encoding is used and the log message about the overfull hbox is in ASCII.

**Question**

Is there anything I can do to obtain a log message in UTF-8? Or would `tinytex` have to deal with it (e.g., by reading bytes and then using `iconv()`)?

Comment: What happens when you use texlive to compile the .tex file? Is the tiny.log in UTF-8? If I remember correctly it keeps the .log file but I don't remember if it is in UTF-8 or not.

Comment: If I run `pdflatex tiny.tex` on the command line I also get the ISO-8859-1 (latin1) log file. You can also keep that file with `tinytex` when you do `tinytex::latexmk("tiny.tex", clean = FALSE)`.

Comment: Then it looks like a bug: the tinytex assumes that the .log files are in UTF-8 while it is clear that it isn't (with texlive). You could convert warnings to errors and see how it arrives to read the file `tinytext` -> `xfun::read_utf8`

Comment: Yes, ideally `tinytex` should handle this more gracefully. It uses `xfun::read_utf8()` to read the log file. Internally, this uses `readLines(con, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE)` unconditionally but checks afterwards via `validUTF8()` and triggering a warning if the log is found to not be UTF-8. What I'm not sure about is whether I can avoid the ISO-8859-1 log file by setting some option for pdflatex.

Comment: FYI this has been fixed in tinytex 0.48: https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/releases BTW, next time please feel free to file a bug report to the tinytex repo on Github (I just saw your post today, otherwise I could have fixed it sooner)

Comment: Yihui, thank you so much for fixing this and for following up here. And apologies for not filing a GitHub issue. When I finally was sure that it wasn't something that I had messed up, other more urgent matters came up and I forgot about this SO question. Do you want to post an answer here that I can accept - or should I update and accept my own partial answer?

Comment: @AchimZeileis No worries at all! I just edited your answer and please feel free to accept it or further edit it if necessary. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues/425) in the R package **tinytex**, which has been fixed in v0.48. Installing the latest version from CRAN should fix the problem:

```r
install.packages('tinytex')
```

---

*(Technical background and partial answer based on off-list feedback from Sebastian Meyer:)*

The log message is not actually latin1-encoded. It rather contains a representation of the characters used for typesetting which may be interpreted by text editors and similar tools as being latin1. In pdfLaTeX this cannot be avoided (only in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX).

The details are explained in [{TeX}: What controls the encoding of the LaTeX log file – and how to change it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131238/what-controls-the-encoding-of-the-latex-log-file-and-how-to-change-it) in the answer by Enrico Gregorio and further comments by David Carlisle. In this discussion it is recommended that the log files should be read as bytes (and not as UTF-8-encoded files).